# How do I filter dates in javascript to only get dates from the last 4 months?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I filter dates in javascript to only get dates from the last 4 months?

For example, if the last date I have is 2014-10-21, I only want data from July to October 2014 (so if I had 2013-10-14, it would be filtered out)

Here's what I have so far:

```
            $.each(dataArray, function(i, data){

        boundaryDates.push(data.values[0].x);
        boundaryDates.push(data.values.slice(-1).pop().x);
            });

            var maxDate=new Date(Math.max.apply(null,boundaryDates));
            var minDate=new Date(Math.min.apply(null,boundaryDates));

            //Convert Date
            var day = maxDate.getDay() < 9 ? '0'+maxDate.getDay():maxDate.getDay();
            var month = maxDate.getMonth() < 9 ? '0'+maxDate.getMonth():maxDate.getMonth();

            var mday = minDate.getDay() < 9 ? '0'+minDate.getDay():minDate.getDay();
            var mmonth = minDate.getMonth() < 9 ? '0'+minDate.getMonth():minDate.getMonth();

            var maximumDate = maxDate.getFullYear()+'-'+month+'-'+day;
            var minimumDate = minDate.getFullYear()+'-'+mmonth+'-'+mday;


    $.each(chartData, function(j, gid){
        if(gid.x >= minimumDate  && gid.x <= maximumDate ){
            gvalues.push(gid);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: people are going to point you [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason?cb=1). 
But for now you should try and explain in more detail what you need.

Comment: you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Comment: please have a look into the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question the right way, this would be the algorithm:

- Take the last (maximum) date from the given array of dates
- Copy that to a new date
- Set the month of that copy to 4 months earlier (`setMonth`)
- Push that copy to a new array and
- Push new dates (using `setDate`) to that array, starting from the copied date until the date to push is the maximum date

In code:

```js
var date0 = new Date()
   ,dateBack = new Date(date0)
   ,last4MonthsDate = [];

dateBack.setMonth(dateBack.getMonth()-4);
last4MonthsDate.push(new Date(dateBack));

while (dateBack < date0) {
     dateBack.setDate(dateBack.getDate()+1);
     last4MonthsDate.push(new Date(dateBack));
}

// show the result
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = 
   last4MonthsDate.map(function (v) {
        return [ v.getFullYear(), 
                 padLeft(v.getMonth()+1), 
                 padLeft(v.getDate()) ].join('-');
      }
   ).join('<br>');

// helper for padding
function padLeft(num, base, chr) {
  var len = (String(base || 10).length - String(num).length) + 1;
  return len > 0 ? new Array(len).join(chr || '0') + num : num;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Kooilnc..it's very helpful for me :)

Comment: Hi @AliTariq, glad I could be of assistance